# Find a number in a list, both the number and list are stored in pandas cells

Tags: python, list, pandas

```
df = DataFrame({'Number': (1, 3, 4, 5), 
                'Lists': ([1], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8])})
```

I want to create another column, "Isin" which is set to 1 if the "Number" is in the "Lists" field for each row i.e.

```
"Isin"
   1
   1
   0
   0
```

I've tried many things all based on `df['Number'].isin(df['Lists'])`... without any luck! It fails with *unhashable type: 'list'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply()` function to loop through rows and check if `Number` is in `List` row by row:

```
df["Isin"] = df.apply(lambda r: int(r.Number in r.Lists), axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***option 1***
Using a fast numpy approach

```
def box(v):
    lens = np.array([len(item) for item in v])
    mask = lens[:,None] > np.arange(lens.max())
    out = np.full(mask.shape, np.nan)
    out[mask] = np.concatenate(v)
    return out

df['Isin'] = (box(df.Lists.tolist()) == df.Number.values[:, None]).any(1) * 1
```

***option 2***
creative zipping

```
f = lambda x: 1 if set.intersection(*map(set, x)) else 0
df['Isin'] = [f(t) for t in zip(df.Lists.values.tolist(),
                                df.Number.values[:, None].tolist())]

df
```

[image]